# ggplot2/ggpubr: Different background colors depending on x axis interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, background, ggpubr

I try to create a Scatterplot where i.e. the background of the area from 0 to 25 on the x axis is red, the area from 25 to 75 is yellow and the area from 75 to 100 ist green, so you can see immediately which values are critical.

I looked up all the questions regarding this topic, but none seems to fit my question. Here is a short reproducable example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

v1 <- c(1, 1, 1)
v2 <- c(1, 0, 0)
v3 <- c(1, 0, 1)
v4 <- c(0, 1, 1)

xG <- c(3, 3, 3, 3)

input <- c(v1, v2, v3, v4)
df <- data_frame(values = input, 
                 module = c(rep("A", length(v1)), 
                            rep("B", length(v2)), 
                            rep("C", length(v3)), 
                            rep("D", length(v4))))

perWorkField <- df %>%
  group_by(module) %>%
  summarise(sums = sum(values)) %>%
  mutate(percent = round((sums / xG) * 100, 2))

g <- ggscatter(data = perWorkField, 
          x = "percent", 
          y = "module", 
          shape = 4) 
g <- ggpar(g, xlim = c(0, 100))
print(g)
```

I prefer to use ggpubr for plotting but it's fully compatible to ggplot2. I'm greatful for any help. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Obviously ggpubr isn't the best solution for this task as the points are in the background behind the colored areas. With ggplot2 the solution would be:

```
ggplot(data = perWorkField) + 
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = percent, y = module), shape = 20) + xlim(c(0, 100)) + 
geom_polygon(aes(x=c(0,25,25,0),
               y=c(0.5,0.5,4.5,4.5)),fill="#F5817A",color=NA) +
geom_polygon(aes(x=c(25,75,75,25),
               y=c(0.5,0.5,4.5,4.5)),fill="#FFFF0044",color=NA) +
geom_polygon(aes(x=c(75,100,100,75),
               y=c(0.5,0.5,4.5,4.5)),fill="#00FF0044",color=NA) + 
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = percent, y = module)) + theme_light()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_polygon` is a simple solution for coloring areas of the plot.

```
g <- ggscatter(data = perWorkField, 
          x = "percent", 
          y = "module", 
          shape = 4) 
g <- ggpar(g, xlim = c(0, 100)) +
geom_polygon(aes(x=c(0,25,25,0),y=c(0.5,0.5,4.5,4.5)),fill="#FFFF0044",color=NA)+
geom_polygon(aes(x=c(25,75,75,25),y=c(0.5,0.5,4.5,4.5)),fill="#00FF0044",color=NA)

print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Do you know a way to keep the crosses visible even when the color is deeper?

Comment: @jeypeu I don't know about *ggpubr*, but in "regular" *ggplot2* you would put the points layer after the polygon (or rectangle) layer so the points were on top of the polygons instead of underneath.

Comment: @aosmith Perfect! I just rewrote it in orgiginal ggplot2 code and it works fine.

Comment: Hi. What's the advantage of using ggpubr instead of cowplot?